# Asignar mediante for valores a JSON

Tags: javascript, json, web

Hola amigos tengo un `JSON` y quiero llenar la parte de `segmetn`, los datos que tengo se obtendrán por inputs, de tipo text, que cree con un metodo for mediante `javascript`

Hacer una ruleta y ese es el `JSON`que necesita `numSegments`, son los participantes, `outerRadius`, es le radio de la ruleta, `segments`, son los segmentos color y texto, `animation` es la animación

Este es el `JSON`:

```
myJSON = {
       'numSegments': numeroparticipantes, // Número de segmentos
       'outerRadius': 170, // Radio externo
       'segments' : [             {
             'fillStyle': '#f1c40f',
             'text': partcipanteuno
           },
           {
             'fillStyle': '#2ecc71',
             'text': participantedos
           },
           {
             'fillStyle': '#e67e22',
             'text': participantetres
           },
           {
             'fillStyle': '#e74c3c',
             'text': participantecuatro
           },
           {
             'fillStyle': '#8e44ad',
             'text': participantecinco
           },
         ],
       'animation': {
         'type': 'spinToStop', // Giro y alto
         'duration': 4, // Duración de giro
         'callbackFinished': 'Mensaje()', // Función para mostrar mensaje
         'callbackAfter': 'dibujarIndicador()' // Funciona de pintar indicador
       }
     };
```

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: Hacer una ruleta y ese es el JSON que necesita numSegments, son los participantes, outerRadius, es le radio de la ruleta, segments, son los segmentos color y texto, animation es la animacion

Comment: A lo que se refiere @alanfcm es que es lo que has tratado de hacer para llenar el JSON, la idea es que trates primero de hacer algo tú y en caso de que no funcione o tengas dudas te podamos orientar :)